# Brake Booster Vacuum Hose on 2018 Jeep Wrangler JL

Tags: vacuum-hoses

The vacuum hose from the Brake Booster looks smaller in external diameter than what was on the 2017 Jeep Wranglers.  Is the inside diameter of this hose 3/8"?  The hose has the "BRAKE 68289577AE > TPC-ET < GB16897" printed on it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!